# Improve Mysql query performance (index in type using explain)

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

Hi everyone I have the following database:

```
`Users`
'id', 'char(36)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, ''
'password', 'varchar(64)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'email', 'varchar(60)', 'NO', 'UNI', NULL, ''
'roles', 'longtext', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'is_active', 'tinyint(1)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''

`Galleries`
'id', 'char(36)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, ''
'user_id', 'char(36)', 'NO', 'MUL', NULL, ''
'name', 'varchar(255)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'description', 'longtext', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'created_at', 'datetime', 'NO', '', NULL, ''

`Images`
'id', 'char(36)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, ''
'gallery_id', 'char(36)', 'YES', 'MUL', NULL, ''
'original_filename', 'varchar(255)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'filename', 'varchar(255)', 'NO', '', NULL, ''
'description', 'longtext', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
```

And the following query:

```
SELECT gal.name, gal.description, img.filename, img.description FROM `homestead`.`users` AS users
LEFT JOIN `homestead`.`galleries` AS gal ON users.id = gal.user_id
LEFT JOIN `homestead`.`images` AS img on img.gallery_id = gal.id
WHERE img.description LIKE '%dog%';
```

When using `explain` in this query I get the `index` result in the `type` field of the Users query. My question is, is there any way to improve this query so it improves this result. I understand the `index` means it goes through all the entries on that particular table, and that may be necessary in this case.

But do you guys see other ways of improving this?

EDIT: Showing indexes for galleries and images tables:

Galleries:

```
'galleries', '0', 'PRIMARY', '1', 'id', 'A', '1', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'galleries', '0', 'UNIQ_F70E6EB7BF396750', '1', 'id', 'A', '1', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'galleries', '1', 'IDX_F70E6EB7A76ED395', '1', 'user_id', 'A', '1', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
```

Images:

```
'images', '0', 'PRIMARY', '1', 'id', 'A', '4', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'images', '0', 'UNIQ_E01FBE6ABF396750', '1', 'id', 'A', '4', NULL, NULL, '', 'BTREE', '', ''
'images', '1', 'IDX_E01FBE6A4E7AF8F', '1', 'gallery_id', 'A', '4', NULL, NULL, 'YES', 'BTREE', '', ''
```

And the explain on the query already without the Users table:

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'gal', NULL, 'ALL', 'PRIMARY,UNIQ_F70E6EB7BF396750', NULL, NULL, NULL, '1', '100.00', NULL
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'img', NULL, 'ref', 'IDX_E01FBE6A4E7AF8F', 'IDX_E01FBE6A4E7AF8F', '109', 'homestead.gal.id', '1', '25.00', 'Using where'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can change the `left join` to `inner join` -- the `where` clause is already doing that, but be explicit.  You can also get rid of `users`, because it is not used.

```
SELECT g.name, g.description, i.filename, i.description
FROM `homestead`.`galleries` g INNER JOIN 
     `homestead`.`images` i 
     ON i.gallery_id = g.id
WHERE i.description LIKE '%dog%';
```

This query should be fine with indexes on `images(gallery_id)`.

If performance is really an issue, you may want to investigate full text indexes so you can possibly change the `like` to `match()`.

Answer (score 1):

(This partially disagrees with Gordon's answer.)

Since the `WHERE` only mentions `images` (`WHERE i.description LIKE '%dog%'`), the Optimizer will probably start with that table.  No regular index is useful for that.  (Gordon's comment on `FULLTEXT` is the 'right' way to improve that.)

The second table is easy to get to if `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see what indexes you have.

(I agree with the rest of Gordon's Answer.)

Another issue...  If the tables become 'huge', you will find that UUIDs perform poorly (because of the randomness).  A million rows is OK, a billion rows will be very slow.

Comment: Just added information for the indexes in the galleries and images tables.

Comment: Please provide the `EXPLAIN`.  Because of the leading wildcard in `'%dog%'`, the query is necessarily slow.